# Emoji Numbers Passing RegEx

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Strange issue.  I have a regex to limit what can be entered into a textfield.  The pattern being used is as follows:

```
NSString *pattern = @"[0-9a-zA-Z'\\-\n ]";
```

This works great except while playing around with the Emoji keyboard I came across a case where the emoji graphic for the numbers 0-9 are being matched by the regex above. None of the other emoji characters including single letters pass the test.  These are the graphics that have say the number 1 surrounded by a box sort of like it is on a button.  How can I prevent that from passing the above pattern?

```
NSString *pattern = @"[0-9a-zA-Z'\\-\n ]";
NSError *error;
NSUInteger match = 1;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];

if ([string length]>0) match = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

if (match != 1) return NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

That emoji is a combination of a Unicode combining codepoint (for an enclosing "keycap" shape) and a normal numeral. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20e3/index.htm

If you want to exclude Unicode characters that can combine with your numerals, there are many possible combining marks that you'd need to look for (such as accent marks). Or you could verify that your string only has characters in the range you care about.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I will post some code as the answer but I am not thrilled with it in the context of what I am doing.  I am sure there is a regex way to solve this but it escapes me for now.

Comment: Trying to do everything in a single regex is folly. It's a beginner trap that many fall into. Don't worry about it. It's rarely the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I wound up solving this.  As I mentioned in a comment I am not thrilled for this approach as I am sure there is a regex way to solve.  If one weren't already using regex I think this is fine, but since I am I think it would be cleaner to fully solve this with regex.  If someone does have a regex answer that can combine with my regex from the OP, please do chime in.

```
if (![string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]) match = 0; 
else
   if ([string length]>0) match = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```